# Properties of classical automata preserved in Büchi automata

Tags: automata-theory, formal-languages

Given two NFW $A$ and $B$, we regarded $A$ and $B$ as Büchi automata.

We can show that the containment property is not preserved in Büchi automata. That is, we can construct a example: $L(A) \subseteq L(B)$ when A and B are both NFW, but $L_\omega(A) \nsubseteq L_\omega(B)$ when A and B are both Büchi automata.

My question is : Are there any interesting properties is preserved in Büchi automata? 
Conversely, given two Büchi automata,  are there any interesting properties is preserved in NFW?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton

Comment: I am no expert, but I believe that being star-free is preserved.

Comment: There is an analogue of the pumping lemma, by essentially the same proof.

Comment: Does "NFW" mean finite nondeterministic automaton? If this is the case, NFA is a much more standard acronym.